# Simplify the query or rewriting the query by omitting UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, zoho

```
SELECT
         '2016 - 17' as 'Years',
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         'Apr 1 - Jan 31' as 'Period'
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    (("year"  = '2016' AND  "month"  >= '04')
 OR ("year"  = '2017' AND   "month"  <= '01'))
GROUP BY  "code" 
UNION ALL
 SELECT
         '2017 - 18' as 'Years',
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         'Apr 1 - Jan 31' as 'Period'
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    (("year"  = '2017' AND  "month"  >= '04')
 OR ("year"  = '2018' AND   "month"  <= '01'))
GROUP BY  "code" 
UNION ALL
 SELECT
         '2018 - 19' as 'Years',
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         'Apr 1 - Jan 31' as 'Period'
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    (("year"  = '2018' AND  "month"  >= '04')
 OR ("year"  = '2019' AND   "month"  <= '01'))
GROUP BY  "code" 
UNION ALL
 SELECT
         '2019 - 20' as 'Years',
         SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
         'Sale' as 'Type',
         "code" as 'FACode',
         'Apr 1 - Jan 31' as 'Period'
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE    "code"  IN
    (
    SELECT "fccode"
    FROM  "fcdetails" 
    )
 AND    (("year"  = '2019' AND  "month"  >= '04')
 OR ("year"  = '2020' AND   "month"  <= '01'))
GROUP BY  "code"
```

From the above query I am getting SUM(svalue) for the period of

```
April 2016 - Jan 2017  
April 2017 - Jan 2018  
April 2018 - Jan 2019   
April 2019 - Jan 2020
```

Is it possible to simplify this query ? I don't want `UNION ALL` - when I use this query in zoho they limit for the total number of `UNION ALL` (139) which I used in full query to get the complete result. Is there any way to rewrite the above query by which we get the same result. Thank you.

Comment: If `year` and `month` are numeric, don't compare them to string values. If they are stored as strings, why?

Comment: I have only year and month in my database there is no date value. I need the above fields for making chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by constructing your `Years` value and then grouping by it as well as `code`. For example:

```
WITH yearly AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN month < 4 THEN year -1  ELSE year END,
                ' - ',
                CASE WHEN month < 4 THEN year ELSE year + 1 END) AS 'Years',
         svalue,
         code AS 'FACode'
  FROM fcjoin
  WHERE code IN (SELECT fccode FROM fcdetails)
  AND month = 1 OR month > 3
)
SELECT Years, 
       SUM(svalue) AS 'Value',
       'Sale' AS 'Type', 
       FACode,
       'Apr 1 - Jan 31' AS 'Period'
FROM yearly
GROUP BY Years, FACode
ORDER BY Years, FACode
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ad141b2b9fe188d1e3032cbe001ad553)

If your environment doesn't support CTEs, you can write `yearly` as a subquery instead:

```
SELECT Years, 
       SUM(svalue) AS 'Value',
       'Sale' AS 'Type', 
       FACode,
       'Apr 1 - Jan 31' AS 'Period'
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN month < 4 THEN year -1  ELSE year END,
                ' - ',
                CASE WHEN month < 4 THEN year ELSE year + 1 END) AS 'Years',
         svalue,
         code AS 'FACode'
  FROM fcjoin
  WHERE code IN (SELECT fccode FROM fcdetails)
  AND month = 1 OR month > 3
) yearly
GROUP BY Years, FACode
ORDER BY Years, FACode
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c87b2679faa72bb234ea0062d2d85dcb)

Comment: sorry I couldn't get it. which all section should i omit to get this run as above code , my tables are fcjoin and fcdetails @Nick

Comment: This is a replacement for your entire query shown in the question

Comment: Only SELECT query statements (SQL) are allowed is shown in zoho while I replace the code ? sorry to bother you. @Nick

Comment: @Gopipuli - sorry, I didn't realise zoho didn't support CTEs (I was working based on the SQL Server tag). I've added a new version of the query to my answer which uses a subquery instead.

Comment: Thank you very much this code works SELECT
   yearly.years,
   SUM(yearly.svalue) AS 'Value',
   'Sale' AS 'Type',
   yearly.code AS 'FACode',
   'Apr 1 - Jan 31' AS 'Period'
FROM ( SELECT
    CONCAT(CASE
      WHEN "month"  < 4 THEN "year" -1
      ELSE "year"
     END, ' - ', CASE
      WHEN "month"  < 4 THEN "year"
      ELSE "year" + 1
     END) AS 'years',
    "svalue",
    "code"
 FROM  "fcjoin" 
 WHERE  "code"  IN
  (
   SELECT "fccode"
  FROM  "fcdetails" 
  )
  AND "month"  = 1
  OR "month"  > 3
) yearly